# Jquery button getting a random image from array

Tags: jquery, arrays, button, random

Playing with jquery and I need help with this part on codepen.

I commented the part I need help with and could someone explain how to get a random image to display on img after I click the button

My code:

```
$('#switch').on('click',function(){
  //Help with this part 
  $('h1').html("I'm supposed to switch the picture but I can't do that");
```

**I need #switch(button) to change the #duck(image) src to random src from the array I provided.**

[CodePen link](http://codepen.io/Agonn/pen/yJwAxV)

Comment: Post the HTML and perhaps the link to the PEN

Comment: Sorry,just did it.

Comment: Start by changing to `<button type="button" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `switch` click handler should look like this:

```js
$('#switch').on('click', function () {
  $('h1').html("I'm supposed to switch the picture but I can't do that"); //Help with this part 
  $(".content").find("img").attr("src", myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length -1)]);
});
```

Comment: Wow thanks,this does what I need it to do. Could you explain the code for me a bit please? Why the  -1 at the end of array and could I use the varable I defined to get random img from array?

Comment: Instead of a variable, you should define `random` as a function, because the global variable as it is written as of now will return every time the same number and will not be of help.

The `-1` is because arrays are zero based [1, 2, 3] will have the 1 at `index 0`, 2 at `index 1` and 3 at `index 2`, while the length would be 3, but you will not have a value at `index 3`, hence the `-1`

Comment: Thank you Marta. How would I make a function which returns strings from arrays randomly ?

Comment: A more generic function would look like this:
`function getRandomArrayItem (array) {
 return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * (array.length - 1))];
}`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the src attribute of your img tag just like below.

```
$("img").attr('src', 'http://example.com/smith.gif')
```

Answer (score 0):

there was problem beacue you initialize random variable globaly.I has just defined it run time by changing this

```
$('#duck').attr('src', myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)]);
```

also remove primary class click event as its not neccessary.try below updated link

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LkvPRq

Comment: So when I want to get a random string/image from array I have to define it as a function and not in variable?

Comment: yes,and If you want to define as variable you need to define it inside the function.